# force close on startanimation in some devices an emulator+logcat

Tags: android, animation, forceclose

My app has a welcome animation,animation type is frame animation,but in some devices like sony z1, and always on emulator it causes force closing, but when i delete that activity app runs normally.

Code of animation is like this:

```
public class welcome extends Activity {
 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome);
     ImageView iv_anim=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_anim_main);
       iv_anim.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation_main);
      AnimationDrawable animmain=(AnimationDrawable) iv_anim.getBackground();
      animmain.start();
    MediaPlayer mplayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.airplane);
    mplayer.start();
       Timer timer=new Timer();
       timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Intent intent=new Intent(welcome.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }, 3625);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
 }
```

AND LOGCAT is like this:

```
08-22 06:09:48.770: I/dalvikvm(603):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-22 06:09:48.770: D/skia(603): --- decoder->decode returned false
08-22 06:09:48.820: D/AndroidRuntime(603): Shutting down VM
08-22 06:09:48.820: W/dalvikvm(603): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.politic/com.example.politic.welcome}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at com.example.politic.welcome.onCreate(welcome.java:20)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  ... 11 more
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  ... 24 more
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:483)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1937)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:664)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:270)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:867)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:804)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1922)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2780)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:113)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:109)
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  ... 27 more
```

Comment: what stack trace do you get back?

Answer (score 0):

The reason seems to be line

```
08-22 06:09:48.990: E/AndroidRuntime(603): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

of your exception stack trace. Your animation might contain too many frames that occupy too much memory. To confirm that you might want to investigate the XML resource for `R.drawable.animation_main`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are getting `Out of Memory error` that means the image which you want to animate may be big size image. So its take time to animate and force close your app.

You can resize your image after convert it to bitmap or use small size image or decode that image file.

Another thing is call this line

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

before

```
 setContentView(R.layout.welcome);
```